# wpdb prepare insert table doesn't work

Tags: php, plugin-development, database, mysql

I followed the introduction to use prepare to insert some data to the table. 
The code is like this:

```
    $wpdb->query(
         $wpdb->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}awpcp_adphotos VALUES
                (ad_id, image_name, disabled, isprimary)
                (%d, %s, %d,%d)",
                $ad_id,
                $ad_img,
                0,
                0));
```

also, disabled and is_primary should be Boolean. But I am not sure what the data type in here.

I also tried

```
$wpdb->insert(
'{$wpdb->prefix}awpcp_adphotos', // Table name
array(
    'ad_id' => $ad_id,
    'image_name' => $ad_img,
    'disabled' => 0,
    'is_primary' => 0,
), // Columns
array(
    '%s',
    '%d',
    '%d',
    '%d'
) // Explicit formatting
```

);

But I haven't got any luck yet. There is no error message when I run the code.

Okay, I found answers in somewhere else.
it should be like this:

```
    $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'awpcp_adphotos', array(
 'ad_id' => $ad_id,
 'image_name' => $image_name,
 'disabled' => $disabled,
 'isprimary' => $isprimary,
  ));
```

I was confused with prefix format.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Have you looked at $wpdb->last_error to find what the error message is?

Comment: Guys, come on. You don't need debug to see that these queries are not correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that first SQL query isn't correct SQL (insert has different syntax) ;) It should be:

```
INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}awpcp_adphotos (ad_id, image_name, disabled, isprimary) VALUES (%d, %s, %d,%d)
```

In second example, I'm almost sure that `ad_id` is not string, and `image_name` is not a number. Of cours I'm only guessing, because I haven't seen this table definition.

Remember that you can always turn error reporting for wpdb on. Just put this line in your code and you will see wpdb errors:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
```